# target="_blank" link with onclick javascript that changes DOM causes page to reload

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, parent, reload

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" onClick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Conversion', 'Website', 'abc', 1]);goog_report_conversion_website();">the link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    goog_report_conversion_website = function() {
    $('#converstion_tracker_iframe').attr('src', '/conversion_tracker/website/');
    }
</script>
```

The expected behaviour of above link should be open up the link in a new window and execute the 2 js functions. However, the goog_report_conversion_website() function is causing the parent page to reload while opening up a new window.

I suspect this is because I am changing the DOM of the parent page, could anyone please confirm with me? Also how to stop the parent page reloading on clicking the link?

EDIT:
looks like change the src of an iframe will cause the page to reload

Comment: I'm not sure I understood yur question xorrectly, byt here the point seems to be that you expect the script to work on the tags of the oage which is opened in the new window.

Comment: I expect the script executed on the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `return false` like this?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" onClick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Conversion', 'Website', 'abc', 1]);goog_report_conversion_website(); return false;">the link</a>
```

Comment: yes I tried, the reload still happens and it will also stop the link being opened, not the desired outcome.